# Flutter - using 'camera' dependency gives me errors/warnings

Tags: flutter, dart

Here's a screenshot of the warnings I receive whenever I try building a .apk or .aab bundle:

[image]

Here's what I've tried so far:
Inside build.gradle file, I've upgraded my targetSdkVersion to 33 & compileSdkVersion to 33 but the warnings/errors still appear after upgrading.

And here's my pubspec.yaml file:

```
dependencies:
  camera: ^0.10.0+4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not receiving errors but warnings, these warnings are just saying that the current method used in the package is deprecated.

You shouldn't worry about it, the maintainer of the package probably know about it and will update the package to fix those warning.

Your code should still work with those warnings.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've never published an app to an app store. Could warnings like these be a reason for rejecting my app during the review process?

Comment: No, not at all. Not that kind of warning.